# java -version resullts -bash: java: command not found (in linux)

Tags: java, linux

Java -version in Linux is not seem to be  working and returing -bash: java: command not found error,though im able to run java related apps.

I have installed jdk in my new linux machine and i have set the environment variable JAVA_HOME using which i can execute JAVA apps and I can echo the java path i set.

Problem is i can not see the java version i have installed ,using the command java -version (i want to know that everything is set fine)

can someone guide me ,what i am missing here.

Comment: Did you update `PATH` too?

Comment: i have used the command : export JAVA_HOME=/home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_151 to set and also i have tried with echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_151 $JAVA_HOME' >>~/.bash_profile
 source .bash_profile  ....is there somthing i am mising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have your java installation directory added to PATH environment variable in order to use java from terminal. For example:

```
export PATH=<your java Directory>/bin:$PATH
```